# Loop based on specific cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hello i have a macro that loops through cells in column G turning each cell TRUE first AND then progressing down the column.

here is the change i want to implement. Cells F11 to F21 have 1 through 4. If cells F1, F3 and F5 have 1 then i would like the adjacent cells in column G1, G3 and G5 need to be TRUE. Then move to cells that have 2 and then 3 and then 4

```
Sub CF_Macro()
'
' CF_Macro Macro
'
Sub SpitValues()

Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Set wsInput = Worksheets("Repline Input")

Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
Set wsSummary = Worksheets("Summary")

With wsInput

    .Range("G11").Resize(10, 1).Value = "FALSE"

    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In .Range("G11").Resize(10, 1)

        rCell.Value = "TRUE"

        DoEvents
        'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        wsSummary.Range("b13:b16").Copy
        wsSummary.Range("z1").Select
        Selection.End(xlToLeft).Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        rCell.Value = "FALSE"

    Next

End With

1   TRUE
2   FALSE
3   FALSE
4   FALSE
1   TRUE
2   FALSE
3   FALSE
4   FALSE
1   TRUE
2   FALSE
```

Comment: You clearly havent provided everything as this wall of text doesnt make any sense what so ever. Please revise your post containing all the information/code

Comment: the goal is the the current macro only loops through column G and turns each cell TRUE and then FALSE before moving on to the next cell. What i want is the loop to look at all the "1" in column F and only turn those cells in column G to be "TRUE" then do the same for all the "2" in column F. But before looking at the "2" turn the existing "TRUE" to "FALSE"

Comment: Why not just have formulas in those TRUE/FALSE cells that compare the column to the left to some specific cell - e.g. `G11` might be `=F11=F$10` (and copy that down for `G12:G20`)?  Then all you have to do is set cell `F10` to `1`, then to `2`, then to `3`, then to `4`.

Comment: because there are several calculations taking place in the background. So for example any cell labelled 1 is a shipping company so when you turn all three of them to TRUE 3 tabs run calculations in the background. 2 = Railroads, so when the 2= TRUE all railroad tabs are running calcs while all other tabs are off. AKA TRUE = Run calcs, FALSE = Dont run calcs

Comment: `Range("G11").Resize(10, 1)` is a needlessly obscure way to refer to `Range("G11:G20")`. In addition to being obscure, it is inefficient since it calls a method on a range object rather than directly constructing the result. In any event, even after your edit I find the question unclear. For example, what do you mean by "then move to cells that have 2 and then 3 and then 4"? All cells which contain those numbers? Cells in a given range? What do you do after you move to such cells?

Comment: Currently the macro turns each cell in that range in column G "TRUE" then there is a set of calcs that happened in the background the results are pasted into a separate spreadsheet that specific cell is turned to "FALSE" and the macro moves to the next cell to repeat the same procedure.My goal is for any "1" in column F the adjacent cells in column G should be turned to "TRUE" everything else should be FALSE.Then once all the calc are completed and info pasted into a different tab turn off the "1" to FALSE.Then go to "2" in column F any adjacent cells should be "TRUE", calc would update